# How to open Google Chrome on Settings / Extensions pages

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I try to pave the way from my application installer/uninstaller to unregister a Chrome extension.

I have tried to start Chrome directly in Settings / Extensions pages with:

```
Chrome.exe chrome://settings/extensions
```

but It doesn't work. Do you know how to do?

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?

Answer (score -1):

Go to "**chrome://settings/browser**" Find **Home Page --> open this page:**
use "*chrome://settings/extensions*" in that..

So every time you start Chrome, it will load Extension page.

Comment: I want to start on extensions page only as needed and not always.

Answer (score -2):

maybe you can try "chrome://apps/" at address bar chrome